# HTML5 form, prevent submission until all all valid elements (checking on focus)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I found this wee bit of code which basically prevents the form being submitted unless all the HTML 5 form elements return valid. http://jsfiddle.net/JgxU7/

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].noValidate = true;

    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        //Prevent submission if checkValidity on the form returns false.
        if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //Implement you own means of displaying error messages to the user here.
        }
    }, false);
}
```

What I would like to do now is modify this so it checks the validity of the form on focus. It should still prevent the form from being submitted until they are all valid but modify the submit button appearance until they are all valid.

Wondering if anyone is able to help or give any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

this is what i have come up with, i know its wrote not very well:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].noValidate = true;

    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        //Prevent submission if checkValidity on the form returns false.
        if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //Implement you own means of displaying error messages to the user here.
        }
    }, false);
}


$('form').each(function (i, form) {
    var $form = $(form),
        $submit = $('[type=submit]', $form);



    $('input, textarea', $form).focus(function(event) {
        var valid = form.checkValidity();
        // change $submit here based on valid or not
        console.log(valid);
        return true;
    });
});
```

Sluap

Comment: Do you want the button's appearance to change as the user is typing stuff into the form? For example, the submit button is disabled until the form is valid, then the submit button enables

Comment: Does it not work if you use `$('input').on('focus', function {});` to validate with that script on an input focus?

Comment: see original question, and yes as they type

Answer (score 0):

A basic answer would be like this: Add this in the for loop

```
(function (thisForm) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
        //Prevent submission if checkValidity on the form returns false.
        if (!thisForm.checkValidity()) {
            // set the button to not valid
        }
        else {
            // set the button to valid
        }
        true;
    }, true);
}(forms[i]));
```

However it would soon be more easier to just use jQuery or other JS utility library to do the DOM manipulation and/or event binding: thus

```
$('form').each(function (i, form) {
    var $form = $(form),
        $submit = $('[type=submit]', $form);

    $form.submit(function (event) {
        // Prevent submission if checkValidity on the form returns false.
        if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //Implement you own means of displaying error messages to the user here.
        }
    }, false);

    $('input, textarea', $form).focus(function(event) {
        var valid = form.checkValidity();
        // change $submit here based on valid or not
        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: i went for your 2nd solution, strangely this prevents default when its all valid, thank you for your time on this

Comment: found a solution to what i want to achive but might not be wrote the best.. see original question